# Is there a good SSMS T-SQL code clean up / formatter plugin?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, format

I'm looking for a good plugin that will automatically do things like upper case all keywords, indent lines appropriately, maybe brackets around reserved words being used as names / aliases, etc.

Comment: Additional Question : Also like it do not touch or format certain block in script.

Answer (score 1):

Redgate's SQL Prompt is the best I've ever used. It's not free though. ApexSQL has a free tool (ApexSQL Complete), but I've never used it...looks like it does the same sort of thing.

Comment: I think ApexSQL Complete is specifically for Visual Studio integration not SSMS.

Comment: @J.D. ApexSQL works in both Visual studio and SSMS. You can have it installed for both, or only one if you so desire.

Comment: Cool I'll check it out. Not sure who downvoted SQL_Hacker, but I gave him an upvote for the suggestion anyway.